# Why doesn't this assignment to a jagged array work?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following code - the assignment to locationSets jagged array won't compile:

```
Location[][] locationSets = null;

var part1 = new Location { Type = "city", Value = "Paris"};
var part2 = new Location { Type = "zip", Value = "90210"};

// following line won't compile with "Invalid expression term '{'
locationSets = {
    new [] { part1, part1 }
};
```

However, if I first place the data into an intermediate jagged array and then set it to the original, it works nicely.

```
Location[][] intermediate = {
    new [] { part1, part1 }
};

locationSets = intermediate;
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required syntax is such that you need to tell it that you're declaring an array, and then it can infer the type correctly:

```
locationSets = new []
{
    new[] { part1, part1 }
};
```

The underlying reason is that array declaration syntax is different from an assigment.

This is described [in the section on simple assigment in the C# standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#simple-assignment):

> In a simple assignment, the right operand must be an expression that
> is implicitly convertible to the type of the left operand.

So in that case,

```
{
     new [] { part1, part1 }
};
```

isn't implicitly convertable, because it isn't a valid declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that this array initializer syntax:

```
... = { ... }
     ^
     +- type missing
```

is only available when you declare the array. Afterwards you actually have to specify the type:

```
locationSets = new Location[][] {
    new [] { part1, part1 }
};
```

or just

```
locationSets = new[] {
    new [] { part1, part1 }
};
```

in which case it will infer that you're creating an array of arrays of locations.

This is just a decision the compiler team made. If you want to know why they made this decision I'm guessing you will either have to ask them or wait for one of them to leave an answer here.